# networkx: how to control radius of circular_layout()?

Tags: draw, networkx

I'm working with random graphs (created with `nx.gnm_random_graph()`). The only neat way to lay these out is with a circular layout. Networkx provides at least two equivalent ways to do this but I don't know how to control the radius of the circle with either of them:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G))
nx.draw_circular(G)
```

Does anybody know how to increase the radius/diameter so the nodes are not so squashed together ?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You can get the effect of changing radius by either reducing the node (and font) size, or increasing the figure size.  Here is an example showing both ways to improve a circular layout of a cycle graph with overlapping nodes.

```
import pylab
import networkx as nx
G=nx.cycle_graph(80)
pos=nx.circular_layout(G)
pylab.figure(1)
nx.draw(G,pos)
pylab.figure(2)
nx.draw(G,pos,node_size=60,font_size=8)
pylab.figure(3,figsize=(12,12))
nx.draw(G,pos)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the radius can be managed by the parameter 'scale' of `nx.circular_layout()`. And you can find more at https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html